# Create sound on iPhone programmatically

Tags: iphone, ipad, audio, ios5, signal-processing

I am trying to find how to create a sound programmatically, because in my app I will have to play a lot of sounds with a different frequency (and with the same timbre and loudness), so I can't make them all before programming.

I have check on this forum and I have found a link to http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/45613-creating-audio-programmatically.html but it isn't fully explained.

Thank you!!

Comment: A lot of people seem to like my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4928589/385559 The book will show exactly how to do what you're looking for: programmatically create an audio file on the iPhone.

Comment: Are you asking how to create custom sound waveforms (DSP stuff), or how to save a sound waveform you have created to files (file formats and file writing)?

Comment: I'm asking how to create a sound programmatically that I can play later on iPhone

Comment: Then try removing the word "file" from your question, and add the signal-processing tag.  Otherwise your question title is misleading.  You don't necessarily need to involve files to create programmatic audio.

Answer (score 0):

ExatAudioFile (`ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL`) and AudioFile (`AudioFileCreateWithURL`) APIs would be a good starting point. They are from AudioToolbox.framework, and available on OS X and iOS.